# How to calculate $e^\pi$ by hand?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

There are some ways to find the values of the form "rational power of rational number" what about nonrecurring numbers? Is there any way to calculate that?

Comment: Exponentiation of positive real numbers is continuous, so you could take ever closer rational approximations to both $e$ and $\pi$ and compute the exponentiation of those.

Comment: You mean calculators use this method ?

Comment: I don't know much about calculators. I suppose they *could* use this method.

Comment: Choose a rational sequence convergent to $\pi$ e.g. $\{p_i\}_{i = 0}^{\infty}$ and calculate $\lim_{i \to \infty} e^{p_i}$.

Comment: @TalhaŞAHİN Your comment suggests this may be a duplicate:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239352/how-do-pocket-calculators-calculate-exponents

Comment: $e^\pi$ is knows as Gelfond's constant, check out the corresponding [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant) for more information, there you can also find a clever way to approximate the constant

Comment: $e^{\pi}$~$20+\pi$

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could compute such a number. One way could be to take a close [rational approximation](http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/mathematics/materialslibrary/pi/pirat.html): $\pi=\frac{a}{b}$. Your goal would then be to find the number $x$, such that $x=e^{a/b}$. This equation could be rearranged to $x^b-e^a=0$, which you could tackle with [root-finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) and an appropriate approximation for $e$.

For example, you could use $\pi\approx\frac{22}{7}$, to get $x^{7}-e^{22}=0$, and then use a sequence such as [$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^7-e^{22}}{7x_n^{6}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). With a perfect approximation for $e^{22}$, this sequence gives you an answer with just $0.13\%$ relative error. Using more precise rational approximations would improve your result but would be harder to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make user190080's point explicit, if $k_0:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\,k_{n+1}:=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-k_n^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-k_n^2}}$ then $(4/k_{n+1})^{2^{-n}}\to e^\pi$ as $n\to\infty$. The square-rooting can be done with a famous method that's a special case of Newton-Raphson; if $y\approx\sqrt{z}$, a better approximation of $\sqrt{z}$ is $(y+z/y)/2$.

But what is you wanted something other than literally the example of $e^\pi$? You can use the Taylor series of $\exp x$, ensuring the argument is small enough for rapid convergence by using $\exp x = (\exp x/2)^2$ repeatedly.

What if you don't want $\exp x$ but $a^x=\exp (x\ln a)$? You can compute logarithms in a similar way; $\ln (1+x)$ has a Taylor series for $|x|<1$, so use $\ln x=2\ln\sqrt{x}$ if need be. (I discussed square-rooting above.)