# What really happens when you use sine, cosine or tangent.

Tags: trigonometry

Please keep in mind that I am only a beginner when it comes to trigonometry. I understand that sine is opposite/hypotenuse, cosine is adjacent/hypotenuse and that tangent is opposite/adjacent. My questions is that when you input sin(B)=AC/Hypotenuse (when hypotenuse and B is given to us). What does the calculator do to get the answer.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["How does a calculator calculate the sine, cosine ,tangent using just a number?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/395600/409).

Comment: Unfortunately, knowing *what a calculator does* to compute the values of $\sin$, $\cos$, etc. is not very useful for a beginner to *understand* trigonometry.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, but it's an interesting question nonetheless (and may make things feel more concrete - it isn't directly helpful but it might remove psychological obstacles).

Comment: To the OP: this question will be closed as a duplicate, but that doesn't mean it's a bad question - it's quite good.