# How do computers calculate an angle from its trig value(s)? How did mathematicians calculate them without computers?

Tags: trigonometry

If I know sin/cos/tan... of an angle x, how do I know the x without look at the table?

How do computers calculate the angle? How the table of sin cos tan was constructed? How the old mathematicians knew this angles without computers?

Comment: Ah, so you're asking about the arc-functions (arcsine, ...).

Comment: yeah but how calculate it by hand?

Comment: Related: ["How does a calculator calculate the sine, cosine, tangent using just a number?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/395600/409) . It's about calculating trig values instead of inverse-trig values, but the ideas are similar. A site search should give you additional relevant results; this kind of question has been asked many times.

Comment: “Old mathematicians”. How old are we talking? Newton-Raphson and other numerical methods were developed in the 17th Century. Maybe the ancient Greeks around the 5th Century BC would have used something like bisection/binary search? Just speculating though

Comment: I thought that was a simple formula for the angle, but apparently you uses some expressions to aproximate. Thanks.

Comment: @thiago: The lack of a "simple formula" in these cases is why we call the trig and inverse-trig functions [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function): they *transcend* "simple" algebra in the sense that there's no polynomial relation between their arguments and their results. The discovery that *power series* (loosely speaking, "infinite polynomials") relate arguments and results was a key advancement in the understanding of the trig functions (and functions in general).

Comment: Oh, now I understand, thank you very much for explaining.